# How to transfer daily OHLC dataframe to weekly or monthly

Tags: r, timetk

In package `timetk`,there is daily `OHLC` dataframe `FANG`, how to transfer to `weekly`(or monthly) OHLC ?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(timetk)

data('FANG')
FANG %>% group_by(symbol) %>%
```